# How do I paginate results from database in a mobile app?

Tags: php, android, json, database, phonegap

Let's say I have hundreds of items fetched from database to be displayed in my mobile app, I can't put all of them on one page, how do I break the results down into pages since I can't use PHP within a mobile app?

Comment: Have you heard of using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` with MySQL (which database I presume you are using on the server side) ?  Look into "pagination with MySQL" for more information on this.

Comment: Sure. I use those almost on a daily basis. You mean I can run sql queries within a mobile application?

Comment: Yes, you can, I do it every day of my life both as an Android developer and a user of other people's Android apps.  How are you calling your database from Android?

Comment: Ajax call to external url, returns say 1 million records from database, json encoded into an array, how do i display 10 items of the array per page?

Comment: So are you saying that you are accessing an external API?  If so, are you saying that this API has no sort of pagination capability?

Comment: I dont know about that.

Comment: Well you need to find out.  If you're in control of that API, you should add pagination, and if not, then I would expect the API to offer this feature.  You are correct in that if it just spams you with a million data points, it's a big problem because where do you put all that data on the UI?